# How to handle MQTT subcription in multiple pods micro service

Tags: node.js, microservices, mqtt, amazon-eks

I have one service called Notification. In this service, we subscribe to the MQTT topic and we get data from the topic. the issue is we have multiple pods for each service. So when MQTT broadcasts the data. these two pods are getting data and do same action. how can restrict to one pod or if have any other solution then please let me know.

thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to use what is known as Shared Subscriptions.

This is a new (optional) feature added to the MQTTv5 specification, but some brokers had propitiatory implementations in their MQTTv3.x brokers.

Shared Subscriptions allow for round robin delivery of messages on to a topic to all clients in the Subscription Group.

More details about Shared Subscriptions can be found here:

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part7-shared-subscriptions/

Comment: what if there is some restriction on upgrading from mqtt3 to mqtt5. Is there any other solution apart from shared subscription?

Comment: While being an optional part of the MQTTv5 spec, there is no requirement for the client to connect using MQTTv5 so a MQTTv3 client should be able to use shared subscriptions if the broker supports it. Also there were brokers that supported none standard implementations before the MQTTv5 spec. But if you are stuck with a broker that doesn't support shared subscriptions then there is no solution

Comment: @hardilib I am using aws iot core. And one of the solution I figured out is to use IOT rule and taking action as http post call on receiving message to mqtt. So whenever any message coming to mqtt, it will be redirected to one of the service pods via http call. As the pods are load balanced hence call will go to only of the service instance. This solves the duplicacy issue but I am wondering about the load/scalding issue. In our case, approx 200 message can comes to mqtt every second, so how many pods are sufficient to handle this much load?

Comment: But that is not a mqtt solution (and not even close to a standard broker)

Comment: I understand that it is not a mqtt solution but will keep it is as a workaround for the time-being. However I tried the shared subscription implementation but facing issue. Added separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582116/java-spring-boot-subscriber-implementation-getting-no-message-when-using-mqtt-sh) If you can take a look on it, that would be really helpful.