# java spring-boot Subscriber implementation getting no message when using mqtt shared subscription

Tags: java, mqtt, aws-iot, paho, aws-iot-core

I am trying to subscribe mqtt topic using AWSIotMqttClient java implementation.
This works totally fine but I am getting issue while using shared subscription.

Below is the sample code I am putting from my production project implementation, Note that: In production we are using mqtt3 and we can't upgrade to mqtt5.

However, I read that mqtt3 supports shared subscription and I am using aws IOT core as broker. For reference reading: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/aws-iot-core-mqtt5-shared-subscriptions-cloudwatch-metrics/

When I am using below implementation and trying to publish the message, hello world is getting printed.

```
public void subscribe() throws AWSIotException {
        final String topic = "commandTopic/demo";
        awsIotMqttClient.subscribe(new IotTopic(topic, (message)->System.out.println("hello world")));
}
```

[image]

But when I am trying to subscribe shared topic, then nothing is getting printed in the console. One warn message is coming as: "Unexpected message received from topic commandTopic/demo"

```
public void subscribe() throws AWSIotException {
        final String topic = "$share/commandGroup/commandTopic/demo";
        awsIotMqttClient.subscribe(new IotTopic(topic, (message)->System.out.println("hello world")));
```

Here also I am trying to publish message the same way as of above.
I am using below maven dependecy:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something, any recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some study I figured out that in order to support shared subscription, we need to implements MqqtCallback interface and override the method(mainly the method "messageArrived"), and then while instantiating 'AWSIotMqttClient', we need to set the custom callback implementation to the client object. Below is the code you can follow. You can also refer [this](https://github.com/yogin16/paho-shared-sub-example/blob/master/example/src/src/SharedSubCallbackRouter.java).

```
public void messageArrived(String topicStr, MqttMessage arg1) throws Exception {
            AWSIotMessage message = new AWSIotMessage(topicStr, AWSIotQos.valueOf(arg1.getQos()), arg1.getPayload());
            //client.dispatch(message);
            boolean matches = false;
            for (String topicFilter : client.getSubscriptions().keySet()) {
                if (topicFilterMatch(topicFilter, message.getTopic())) {
                    final AWSIotTopic topic = client.getSubscriptions().get(topicFilter);
                    scheduleTask(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            topic.onMessage(message);
                        }
                    });
                    matches = true;
                }
            }
            if (!matches) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected message received from topic " + message.getTopic());
                //LOGGER.warning("Unexpected message received from topic " + message.getTopic());
            }
        }
```

```
public boolean topicFilterMatch(String topicFilter, String topic) {
        if (topicFilter == null || topic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (topicFilter.startsWith("$share/")) {
            topicFilter = topicFilter.replaceFirst("\\$share/", "");
            topicFilter = topicFilter.substring(topicFilter.indexOf('/') + 1);
        }
        String[] filterTokens = topicFilter.split("/");
        String[] topicTokens = topic.split("/");
        if (filterTokens.length > topicTokens.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < filterTokens.length; i++) {
            if (filterTokens[i].equals("#")) {
                // '#' must be the last character
                return ((i + 1) == filterTokens.length);
            }
            if (!(filterTokens[i].equals(topicTokens[i]) || filterTokens[i].equals("+"))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return (filterTokens.length == topicTokens.length);
    }
```

This is the configuration code for instantiating AWSIotMqttClient:

```
public AWSIotMqttClient awsIotMqttClient(String clientId) throws AWSIotException {
        final AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(awsIotEndpoint, clientId, awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey);
        if (client.getConnectionStatus() == AWSIotConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED) {
            //client.setNumOfClientThreads(5);
            client.setKeepAliveInterval(5000);
            client.connect();
        }

        AwsIotWebsocketConnection conn = (AwsIotWebsocketConnection) client.getConnection();
        conn.getMqttClient().setCallback(new CustomMQTTCallback(client));
        return client;
    }
```